# How can I center an element when window resizes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to align an anchor tag to the middle of an image. The image size is dynamic so I have to calculating the height and then taking have that value and assigning it to the var. I'm having trouble making it do the same thing when you resize the window. please help.

```
$(function () {
    var imageHeight = $('.slide img').height();
    var slickImageCalc = imageHeight / 2;

    function moveArrows() {
        $(".slick-arrow").css("top", slickImageCalc + "px");
    }

    if ($(window).width() < 992) {
        moveArrows();
    }

    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width() < 992)
        {
            moveArrows();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This could be done (much more easily) with CSS. Is that an option for you?

Comment: No css isn't an option.

Comment: Then please revise your question to explain what isn't working, or how it's working incorrectly. "Having trouble" is a bit vague. A simplified HTML snippet would be great, too.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, I was defining the variables and that value never changes. so I moved the variables inside the if statement and I was able to clean up the rest.

```
$(function () {
        $(window).resize(moveArrows);
        moveArrows();
});

function moveArrows() {
        if($(window).width() < 992) {
            var imageHeight = $('.slide img').height();
            var slickImageCalc = imageHeight / 2;
            $(".slick-arrow").css("top", slickImageCalc +"px");
        }       
}
```